# JDBC вставка данных в две связанные таблицы в одном коннекшине

Tags: java, jdbc

Подскажите, можно ли вставить в одном connection данные в две связанные таблице? Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Можно. Лучше делать это в транзакции.

Comment: в данном случае, если использовать много стейтментов , то лучше использовать executeBanch()? или просто каждый раз executeUpdate()?

Comment: Когда есть возможность пакетировать запросы, лучше это делать, но при вставках данных с взаимосвязями такой возможности обычно нет.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо вам